# How to iterate through a 2D vector with an unknown size?

Tags: c++, loops, 2d-vector

I'm trying to access the int values inside of a 2D vector which has an unknown number of rows and columns.

I have tried this:

```
for(vector<int> vec : matrix){
        for(int i : vec){
            queue_lista.push(vec[i]);
        }
    }
```

and this:

```
vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
vector<int>::iterator col;
for (row = nums.begin(); row != nums.end(); row++) {
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        //queue_lista.push(nums[col][row]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can the size be unknown if it's a `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet, `i` takes on the values in the vector, not the indexes.  So you should just use `push(i)` not `vec[i]`.

In your second snippet, `col` is an iterator, not an index.  So you shouldn't use that with subscripting either.  `*col` is your data.

---

Performance note: The first snippet will be much more efficient if you let `vec` be a constant reference instead of a copy.